# vlookup first word of the cell to first word of the table array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First word match vlookup

### worksheet 1 :

```
dave davidson friend         (cell A1), ?  (cell B1)
```

### worksheet 2 :

```
dave davidson friend brother (cell A1), 23 (cell B1)

gang gang nice               (cell A2), 54 (cell B2)
```

I want to vlookup such that the result is 23

Comment: You need to inform what you have attempted. SO expects user effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10,MATCH(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)& "*",Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10,0))
```

***Sheet1:***

[image]

***Sheet2:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
=VLOOKUP( "*" &  A1 & "*",Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)
```